# the characterization of the center of a finite non-nilpotent group which contained in a maximal Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non-nilpotent group and $G \cong (C_{p^n} \times C_p) \ltimes C_q$, where $P \cong (C_{p^n} \times C_p)$ is an abelian non-cyclic and non-normal sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, which is maximal subgroup of $G$. Also we have $Z(G) \leq P$ and $G' \cong C_q$.  I want to know why $Z(G) \cong C_p \times C_{P^{n-t}}$, where $t \mid q-1$.
Note that $C_q$ is a cyclic group of order $q$.
Note that $p,q$ are prime number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $p$ and $q$ are primes. Also, your statement does not appear entirely correct to me, see the last paragraph below.

The automorphism group of the cyclic group of prime order $C_{q}$ is cyclic, of order $q-1$. Now
$$
G / C_{G}(C_{q})
$$
is isomorphic to a non-trivial subgroup of the automorphism group of $C_{q}$. Moreover $C_{G}(C_{q}) \ge C_{q}$, and clearly
$$
C_{G}(C_{q}) = Z(G) \times C_{q}.
$$
It follows that $P/Z(G)$ is cyclic, of order $p^{s}$ dividing $q-1$. Now what are the subgroups $H$ of $P$ with this property? If $a$ is a generator of $C_{p^{n}}$, and $b$ is a generator of $C_{p}$, clearly $a^{p^{s}} \in H$. Now distinguish two cases, according to whether $b \in H$ or $b \notin H$.

Comment: See [this reference](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_prime_order#Automorphisms).

Comment: ok, thats right